# Apache - mod rewrite with virtual host question

Tags: apache-2.2, mod-rewrite, mod-wsgi

I have Apache 2.0 set up with a virtual host like this:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
     ServerName wackystore
     ServerAlias wackyprojects
     Alias /media/admin /opt/python/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/$
     Alias /media /opt/DjangoProjects/wacky/media
     #mod_wsgi setup
     WSGIScriptAlias / /opt/DjangoProjects/wacky/django.wsgi
</VirtualHost>
```

I have our DNS set up so both "wackystore" and "wackyprojects" go to this server.

What I want to have happen is for mod rewrite to change the url for wackyprojects to wackprojects/tools.

Examples:

```
http://wackystore -> no change

http://wackystore/something -> no change

http://wackyprojects/ -> http://wackyprojects/tools

http://wackyprojects -> http://wackyprojects/tools

http://wackyprojects/something -> no change
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^wackyprojects$ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/*$
RewriteRule .* http://wackyprojects/tools [R,L]
```

"If the HTTP_HOST is `wackyprojects` and the REQUEST_URI is `/` or nothing at all, then rewrite the request to `http://wackyprojects/tools` and stop there."

Comment: Wow that's so simple!  Now why couldn't I figure that out from the docs :-(  Thanks a bunch!

Comment: What are the [NC] and [R,L] for?

Comment: NC = no case (case insensitive), R = redirect, L = last (no more rules processed). See more here: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteflags

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteEngine   on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST}    wackyprojects [NC]
RewriteRule ^/$             http://wackyprojects/tools [L,R]
```

- `NC` flag means no case
- `L` - Last rule and `R` - force redirect